# CSS: background image for submit button

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have styled submit button with custom background image. But it shows differently on different browsers.

Almost all browsers shows it correct:

[image]

But on 2 it have extra height:

[image]

Can anyone point what wrong is with my markup?

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]{
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17055243/icons.png) -99px 0px  no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:none;
    float:left;
    margin:30px 0 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="placeholder" value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

**Tested:**

- IE 8.0 **good**
- IE 7.0 **good**
- iPhone **good**
- Chrome 24.0 **good**
- Firefox 18.0.2 **good**
- Safari 5.1  (Mac OS X 10.7.1) **good**
- Opera 12.14 (Windows 7 32-bit) **good**
- Safari 5.1.7 (Windows 7 32-bit) **extra height**
- Opera 11.51 (Mac OS X 10.7.1) **extra height**

[Live demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taran2l/Qucjj/).

Comment: On Opera 12.14, Windows XP, it works perfectly.

Comment: The submit button is the right size. It's the input box that is wrong. Only thing I can think of is you might need to set the `line-height` and/or `font-size`. Use developer tools to see if you can find any browser specific stylesheet rules that might be getting set, that you aren't specifically overriding.

Comment: You may also have to explicitly say things like `padding: 0;` just to make sure that the browser defaults are completely out of the way. Also worth looking at would be `normalize.css`, just stick that before all of your custom styles.

Comment: Then you aren't doing it right. You need to style the text input - I can't be more clear.

Comment: @crush, oh sorry. Just read your comment not corect, so I tried on submit button, not text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
It will give a fix height to the element.

```
input[type="text"]{
    margin:30px 0 0;
    width:226px;
    color:#999999;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:italic;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right:none;
    background-color:#ededed;
    float:left;
    height:28px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me the height of the textbox is different not the submit button. Try setting the height of the textbox.

Comment: This is exactly what the problem is. The submit button is consistent in both images, but the text box is not. Style the text box.

Answer (score 1):

I see in the second search bar, the text is italic and looks slightly smaller. I think the search bar is adjusting to the text and making itself smaller, which makes the search icon appear larger.

What you probably need to do is add this to your stylesheet where the placeholder is controlled:

```
{font-style:normal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons & input textfields have different default values for borders, margins, padding, etc. First of all you have to put this to both submit buttons and textfields

```
margin:0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
```